# How to post js string to C# in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP and I am trying to take a string in my JS code and post it to my controller so that I can use it to query my database.

**JavaScript**

```
function findEmployees(userCounty) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")',
        data: JSON.stringify(userCounty),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(userCounty);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index (string userCounty)
    {
        var query = //use linq to query database
        return View(query);
    }
```

I only ever get the "success" alert when I use a JsonResult function in my Controller but I need it to eventually return a LINQ query to the View(); function and that hasn't worked when using a JsonResult function. Any ideas would be helpful. I don't necessarily have to use ajax if there is a better way. I just need a way to pass the string  stored in userCounty to my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change your controller method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([FromBody]string userCounty)
{
    var query = //use linq to query database
    return View(query);
}
```

For viewing the page, you'll need

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

Comment: I have implemented what you put here and I can see that the string is being passed into the function! However, when I am returning the query to the view nothing shows up on the page. Its just blank. In the console I am getting a message "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."

Comment: The page loads normally when I remove the [HttpPost] and [FromBody] but the ajax fails. Do I need to make a separate function to receive the string and then pass it into the Index function?

Comment: You will need one end-point for get, and one end-point for post.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on that at all? I'm sorry, I am very new to ASP

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Does this mean that I need to put the query in the [HttpGet] function?

Comment: Your welcome :-) I guess you are displaying an initial view, so the query should be in the post method.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer if things are solved :-) BR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225748/discussion-between-zap-00-and-roar-s).